video_player 2.8.7 flutter error building app
when i adding video_player 2.8.7 to my flutter project, with flutter 3.22 , when just pub get and run project from scratch, this error happened:

Could not find gradle-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1)

Error happened for video_player_android
I checked external libraries and the problem is in video_player_android 2.5.0 that automatically added to my project and gradle 7.2.1 that defines in it. I changed gradle to high or down version of gradle but nothing happened. what should I do?
name: appname
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
sdk: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_lints: ^2.0.2
get: ^4.6.6
flutter_svg: ^2.0.10
country_code_picker: ^3.0.0
pin_code_fields: ^8.0.1
shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
flutter_screenutil: ^5.9.1
glass_kit: ^4.0.1
video_player: ^2.8.7
flutter:
uses-material-design: true
assets:

assets/images/
assets/icons/

fonts:
- family: Poppins
fonts:
- asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf
weight: 800
- asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
weight: 700
- asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
weight: 600
- asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
weight: 500
- asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
weight: 400
- asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf
weight: 300

What is the gradle version you are using in your project? Please also share your pubspec.yaml file.

gradle 7.6.3 -all . i edited my question and add my pubspec.yaml file.
